# Proclaim command with multiple paragraphs

Tags: theorems, paragraphs, plain-tex

In page 131 of "TeX for the Impatient", it says the followings for `proclaim` command:

```
\proclaim ⟨argument⟩.␣⟨general text⟩\par

This command ``proclaims'' a theorem, lemma, hypothesis, etc.
It sets <argument> in boldface type and the following paragraph in
italics. <argument> must be followed by a period and a space token,
which serve to set off <argument> from <general text>.
<general text> consists of the text up to the next paragraph
boundary, except that you can include multiple paragraphs by putting them
within braces and ending a paragraph after the closing right brace.
```

Maybe I'm not understanding these well, since when I wrote the following

```
\proclaim Theorem 1.
{What I say is not to be believed.

What I say is not to be believed.}\par
```

I get an error from TeX. What is the correct usage of `proclaim` with multiple paragraphs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\proclaim` is defined as

```
\outer\def\proclaim #1. #2\par{\medbreak
  \noindent{\bf#1.\enspace}{\sl#2\par}%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount \removelastskip\penalty55\medskip\fi}
```

So the "title" is delimited with a period and a space, and the content by a `\par`.  If you'd like to have more than one paragraph inside the proclaim, you can use `\endgraf` like so:

```
\proclaim ⟨argument⟩.␣⟨general text⟩.
This command ``proclaims'' a theorem, lemma, hypothesis, etc.
It sets <argument> in boldface type and the following paragraph in
italics.\endgraf
<argument> must be followed by a period and a space token,
which serve to set off <argument> from <general text>.
<general text> consists of the text up to the next paragraph
boundary, except that you can include multiple paragraphs by putting them
within braces and ending a paragraph after the closing right brace.

\bye
```

Note that the last empty line before `\bye` delimits the `\proclaim`.

Comment: Do you mean it is a mistake in this book?

Comment: @Z.H. Looks to me like it is.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `\proclaim` is a typical example of Knuth's writing style. He rarely uses multiparagraphs statements, so the main argument of `\proclaim` is delimited by `\par`.

The macro has two arguments:

```
\outer\def\proclaim #1. #2\par{\medbreak
  \noindent{\bf#1.\enspace}{\sl#2\par}%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount \removelastskip\penalty55\medskip\fi}
```

The first argument is delimited by `.`, so it is everything from `\proclaim` up to the first `.` that appears at the outer brace level. This is meant to be the statement's number. The second argument is delimited by `\par`, which means either an explicit `\par` command or an empty line, because this is converted to `\par` during tokenization.

Note that the macro is declared `\outer`, so it can appear neither in the replacement text of another macro nor in the argument to a `\write` command. Also the macro is not `\long`, so hiding a `\par` in a pair of braces as you tried is not allowed (as before, leaving an empty line is the same as typing `\par`).

One could ask what's the purpose of the conditional `\removelastskip` in the definition; probably it is there because a statement might end with an itemized list that the author could have defined with some vertical space at either end.

Is `\proclaim` good for anything? No. It's there just to show how a macro for theorem statements can be defined. The idea is that Plain TeX users will define their macros based on their own needs.

A mildly complex mathematical paper will most probably need multiparagraph statements and also macros for enumerated lists, with at least a rudimentary cross reference system.

A better definition would use a different delimiter than `\par`:

```
\long\def\proclaim#1#2\endproclaim{\medbreak
  \noindent{\bf#1.\enspace}{\it\ignorespaces#2\par}%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount \removelastskip\penalty55\medskip\fi}
```

(note that I changed `\sl` into `\it`; I consider slanted type, albeit loved by Knuth, as not being a real advancement in the typographical craft).

With that redefinition you can type

```
\proclaim{Theorem 1}
What I say is not to be believed.

What I say is not to be believed.
\endproclaim
```

Note also the “normal argument” status, which I prefer, for the header argument. It might also be as before with

```
\long\def\proclaim#1. #2\endproclaim{\medbreak
  \noindent{\bf#1.\enspace}{\it#2\par}%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount \removelastskip\penalty55\medskip\fi}
```

and the input should be

```
\proclaim Theorem 1.
What I say is not to be believed.

What I say is not to be believed.
\endproclaim
```